# Scala: currying vs closure

Tags: scala, closures, currying

I can use closure to define function like this:

```
def product(x: Int) = (y: Int) => x * y
val productBy3 = product(3)
println(productBy3(6)) // 18
```

OR, using currying:

```
def curriedProduct(x: Int)(y: Int) = x * y
val productBy3 = curriedProduct(3)_
println(productBy3(6)) // 18
```

Any advantage/disadvantage one approach has over other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is an example of a method returning a function. The second is an example of a method with multiple parameter lists.

The way you use them, there is no difference.

When called as `product(3)(6)`, the second may be a bit faster, but not to an extent that would normally be a concern.

I would use the first form when the expected way to call it would be with `product(3)`, and use the second form if the normal way to call it would be `product(3)(6)`.

Lastly, I'd like to suggest the possibility of

```
def product(i: Int, j: Int) = i * j
val productBy3 = product(3, _)
println(productBy3(6)) //18
```

I don't really see any upsides of using the second form instead of either this alternative or the first alternative in this situation. Using multiple parameter lists may help type inference in scala 2 (see https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html), but there is no problematic inference here anyway.